# How do you code <ObjectType> into a new class

Tags: java, collections

I'm writing a java based rpg. At the heart of it I have made a custom collection like class which can be set up with the properties of any java collection, and has full concurrency controls (including customizable policies for choosing what type of operation to do next eg writes first), and has enhanced searching capabilities. I use it extensively throughout the threaded parts of my game. It's not needed but I want to make it compatible with the java in built collections. 
I can't seem to find how to program the object type parameter into a new class, eg **List< Integer>**

Can anyone help with this or point me in the right direction please.

Thank You!

Comment: `public class MyList<T> {}` is your class declaration.

Comment: What is “how to program the object type parameter into a new class” supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

Generic types are used for that purpose. So your class would probably look like this:

```
public class MyList<T>{
    private T[] list;
    private int size;
    public void add(T item){}
    public void search(T item){}
    //.etc
}
```

Or you can just implement `List<T>` interface for that. But I recommend you use synchronized collections in `java.util.concurrent.*` package if you don't have to implement your list manually.